# The difference between IE Version 9,8,7 and Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome

I make a page and retrieve some mp4 videos.However, these videos plays on Chrome successfully but in ie version does not play.

Is there any idea ? May it be a encoding problem ? If it is , chrome play my videos with webkit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, this may be a encoding problems, you can use various tools to encode it .